# fundamental group of a point and a sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm wondering whether the fundamental group of a point and a sphere are the same?
If it is, then the topological of a point and a sphere are the same?
and we can deform a sphere to a point and still keep the topology?

Would like to know more formal answer or a proof.

Comment: Yes, in both instances the fundamental group is the same. No, this does not mean that the two are topologically the same; that is, they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: No, you just have that both are simply connected. You cannot deform one to the other homotopically in the ambient space considered.

Comment: If all the homotopy groups are the same (by a given induced map), then for nice spaces they are homotopically equivalent. But $\pi_2(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is not trivial. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem#Spaces_with_isomorphic_homotopy_groups_may_not_be_homotopy_equivalent

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering whether the fundamental group of a point and a sphere are the same?

Yes. They're both simply connected, assumed you are asking for the fundamental group and the 2-sphere $S^2$.

> If it is, then the topological of a point and a sphere are the same?

Absolutely no. You're very far from the properties required to two spaces to be homeomorphic: even if they had the same homotopy type that would not be true. For this specific instance the easiest way to prove that they're not homeomorphic is that they're obviously not bijective.

A more friendly counterexample to the general statement that if two spaces are homotopy equivalent then they are homeomorphic is this: take $X = \mathbb R$ with the usual topology and $Y = \left[ 0,1 \right]$ with the induced topology. They're both contractible, but $Y$ is compact, while $X$ isn't.

> Can we deform a sphere to a point and still keep the topology?

The answer is again no. There's no way to deform a sphere to a point: the sphere is not contractible. For showing this the fundamental group is not sufficient; you should look at the second group of homotopy $\pi^2$. Instead of showing that $\pi^2(S^2) = \mathbb Z$, which is not really immediate, I'll give you an example to understand the intuition behind this result.

When we say *deformation* we really mean that it exists a continuous function from $S^2 \times I \to \{ p \}$, that we can imagine as a deformation over time of $S^2$. The point is, this deformation has to be **continuous**, and that means in a certain sense we can't generate or eliminate *holes*. Now, $S^2$ contains an empty 2-dimensional hole, and there's no way to keep this hole while stretching $S^2$ to a point: sooner or later it must vanish; and that can't be done from a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer

Comment: Nice answer. Though I think the easiest way to see that a sphere and a point are not homeomorphic is to remember that a homeomorphism is also bijection (of sets).

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's the easiest :)